# Supplant torrent download with an Http download?

Tags: bittorrent, http

When downloading a large file, is it possible to download it via both the BitTorrent and HTTP protocols?

For example, when downloading an Ubuntu ISO image, I would like to download via BitTorrent, but when the torrent is slow to download, it could be supplanted with an official HTTP URL.

(I think this should be possible for HTTP servers that support HTTP resume).

Are there any BitTorrent clients that support such a feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sort of. "[webseed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29#Web_seeding)s" would allow this, assuming the torrent was set up with a webseed (which is nothing more than a copy of the file on regular web hosting.

I believe amongst others, utorrent supports this.

Comment: Most torrent clients like µTorrent allow to add "webseeds" while torrent download is running. Just add one or more web-links to webseeds section in the properties dialog of a download.

Comment: Thanks, webseeds was the keyword that I needed to search further. Have added an answer with a list of clients that support it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Journeyman's answer, I found the list of clients that support webseeding ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients)). I am not sure which among these allow `webseeds` to be added by the user (not just the torrent creator).

As of Aug 2011,

- µTorrent
- BitTyrant
- Vuze
- BitComet
- ABC
- BitTornado
- BitTorrent
- BitTorrent
- BTG
- Deluge
- Folx
- KTorrent
- LimeWire
- OneSwarm
- qBittorrent
- Shareaza
- SoMud
- Torrent Swapper
- TorrentFlux
- Transmission
- Tribler